# How to merge multiple KML points into one file?

Tags: qgis, point, kml, merge

I made 20 KML points in Google Earth, and put it in gis - I want to save it in a single file, right now they are 20 different files. How can it be done?

What I want to have is a single gpx file.

Comment: Do you mean KML?

Comment: yes, i'd like to have a single gpx file to put on my gps

Comment: I am new to GIS, and the QGIS operation. This solution here was helpful

Comment: what if you have a mix of pts, lines and plygons?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to get what you want in essentially one step, using the "Merge vector layers" tool. You can search for it in the toolbox, or find it via the menu bar at Vector>Data Management Tools>Merge vector layers.

[image: Merge Vector Layers]

From there, it's a simple matter of selecting all of your open KMLs in the "Layers to merge" section and choosing the export file location, name, and .gpx format.

[image: Export to file]

[image: Merge Tool]

Comment: Thank you! It really is simple, thank you for your time with all this!