# How can I merge 30 lines from a kml into 1 shp in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, kml, merge, civil3d

I have almost the same question that was solved here ([How to merge multiple KML points into one file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/231501/96160)) but I cannot find the same options as the solution (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/231506/96160).

I have 30 separate lines in a Google Earth kml. I need to merge them into one shapefile so I can import that to AutoCAD Civil 3D 2016. Right now they are 30 different vector layers.

How do you get the same options in version 2.18.7 on Windows as [JohnR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/71740/johnr) has in version 2.18.0 on Mac?

This is a screen shot from v2.18.7 on Windows.
[image]

This is a screen shot from v2.18.0 on Mac.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRiOf.png]

Comment: Did you scroll to the right? It looks as if there is more to the right and you may find the button.

Comment: Yes, but it still does not let you select multiple layers. It lets you open a file from the computer, but it does not open .kml files.

Comment: Are all the kmls definitely the same geometry? Shapefiles can only store a single geometry type.

Comment: Yes, it is a single kml with multiple line segments about 1,500 feet in length.

Comment: What you're trying to do is fundamentally different to what the other question is about.  The other question is focused on combining multiple KML files into one shapefile.  You're trying to merge line segments in a KML into one line and convert to shapefile. These are two separate steps.

Comment: I missed that where he said "different files"

Comment: The segment don't need to be merged into one line. I just need them all in one shp file so I don't have to do a save as on all 30 segment from Qgis and mapimport all 30 in Civil 3D.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a KML to a shapefile, you simply need to open the KML in QGIS, right click on the layer, and click on Save As.  Then choose shapefile.

Add Vector Layer:

[image]

Select your KML:

[image]

Save As...

[image]

Save it as an ESRI Shapefile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Fezter. I was afraid this was going to be the only way. I will do a save as on all 30 line segments then use the merge shapefiles to one option.

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  The above will convert all 30 line segments from a KML to Shapefile.  No need to merge them. You're simply converting a single kml to a single shapefile, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am converting a single kml to shp, but when I add the kml layer it splits all the line segments into individual layers. The kml is a polyline/path it is 30 separate line segments.